# side by side <div> and site centering

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to convert my site from using tables to just using css and divs but I'm running into a lot of problems with trying to figure how to exactly do it, I've been looking for tutorials on centering a site with css and how to put divs side by side but I can't really find one that does both and I keep getting confused by how to exactly achieve this, I asked around a bit and I got told to use absolute positioning but still I can't really wrap my head around this.

So basically how would I arrange the 2 central div side by side while keeping the whole thing centered in the browser? The following image is the layout I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

the blue boxes are eventual other stuff I might want to put in them, such as a blog requiring again the use of side by side divs.

right now I have the following layout:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="banner"> banner </div>
  <div id="navbar"> navigation links </div>
  <div id="body"> stuff </div>
  <div id="footer"> stuff </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note in the answer below - the HTML attributes values are in quotes, as in `id="banner"`.

Comment: @SurrealDreams: Yes, though HTML5 allows to omit those if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General idea: http://jsfiddle.net/JjbJE/

A little specific but provide you a great adventure to learn HTML | CSS : http://jsfiddle.net/JjbJE/3/

`float:left|right` this property does the side by side trick

`clear:both` this property clear away the float property

Other things are pretty easy to learn, just head to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Comment: nice learning resource, I knew about w3schools (and that's where I'm learning most of the stuff) but this jsfiddle just looks amazing

Comment: @Jackomel I know. But still your best friend should be your notepad and offline browser.

Answer (score 3):

First you need a main container to center everything. Then two separate divs. See the HTML below:

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="box">Left Box</div>
   <div class="box">Right Box</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS you will need:

```
#main{
   width:960px;
   margin:0 auto;
}

.box{
   width:450px;
   float:left;
   border:solid 1px #000000;
}

.clear{
   clear:both;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like you edited your initial question but my answer should still do the trick.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, I'll try right away and see if I can finally solve this riddle

Comment: http://www.jackomel.com/images/screens/1811.png it didn't really turn as I expected it would...

Comment: Ok. Which element did you try to float? Can you update your question with the exact HTML that you have in place, minus the page copy and let me know what element you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to have a centered wrapper class and contain the divisons inside of that:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <div id="middle">
    <div class="main-article clearfix"></div>
    <aside></aside>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Then to style, center the wrapper, float the aside and main-article:

```
.wrapper { width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; /* the auto centers it */ }
header, footer, aside, { display: block; }
.main-article { width: 50%; float: right; }
aside { width: 50%; float: left; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

**Note:** This is untested, and uses the [clearfix from the HTML5 Boilerplate](http://h5bp.com/q).

**Update 01.22.2014:** This "Holy Grail Layout" has ben solved by Flexbox. Check out [Solved By Flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/) for more information on recreating this layout (and many more).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my general overview on converting to a CSS based layout - if you have a table based layout, this is a good plan - in the end you can do more, Google will like you more, and it's much cooler.

My strategy is to look at all the groups of things on your page.  Whatever needs to go into a group together, put inside a div.  Assign this div a class and/or id to style it.  If the divs are grouped, put them together in a div too.

In your case, you have two chunks of content to group inside of divs.  Style them to be the size and shape you like, background, border, whatever is needed.  Then group them together in an additional div, and center it.  This and the rest of the page content can go inside a container div, which will determine the width of the page, how it's aligned, etc.